# Can't run the ActionAndVision sample on iPhone 11 pro

Tags: ios, ios14, coreml, apple-vision

Trying to run the demo project for wwc20-10099 ActionAndVision in a iPhone 11 Pro/iPhone Pro using the supplied sample.mov, or real board. The entire time the app has the "Locating board" overlay instead of finding the board before the bean bags begin to be tossed.

And I also have this issue:

Error Domain=com.apple.vis Code=12 "processing with VNANERuntimeProcessingDevice is not supported" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=processing with VNANERuntimeProcessingDevice is not supported}

Environment:
Big Sur 11.0 beta 20A5343i
XCode 12.0 beta 12A8179i
iPhone 11 Pro on iOS 14 beta 4
iPhone 11 on iOS 14 beta 4

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fixed with iOS 14 beta 5